# IE11 ActiveX control Modal dialog

Tags: c++, delphi, activex, internet-explorer-11

I work on an active x control(C++/Delphi) (and yes, I know, ActiveX will eventually be retired by MS), and an issue we're having is that in IE11 dialogs spawned by active x controls can no longer be modal. This creates a problem when the dialog absolutely needs to be modal(such as "save your work now" dialogs).

Any ideas? I've already tried EnableModeless in the OLE interfaces to no effect(true or false).

Comment: I don't think any browser should allow modal dialogs. If it's worked in the past, it was probably by luck, or something overlooked (and later patched). The last thing anybody wants is some window popping up preventing them from using their entire browser. "modal" dialogs should be self-contained within the HTML page.

Comment: Oh I agree with you. The degree of power an active x control has is terrifying. Its a business need because long ago "someone" wrote an active-x wrapper for our program so we didn't have to rewrite the whole thing for the web.

Comment: Well, like I said, unfortunately it seems as if Microsoft has patched a long time vulnerability which your ActiveX control was taking advantage of. Also, ActiveX isn't going anywhere, Windows still widely relies on it. It's the support within IE which is going away. You may ask your users to downgrade their version of IE. Also, have you tested in the new browser in Windows 10? I'm willing to bet that's the point they cut ActiveX support.

Comment: Have you considered re-engineering your shut down process to check the status of a flag during formerly modal situations?  As long as the flag is set, you wait for input from the user and provide some little UI event to indicate the state of things (like flashing the title bar or something.)  It's a balancing act because there may be multiple triggers for the shutdown process.  (You don't want to get into an endless loop preventing a legitimate use case.)